# LINK : fatal error LNK1221: подсистема не может быть логически выведена, а должна быть определена

Tags: windows, ассемблер

Проблема. Я создаю пустой проект в Visual Studio Express 2010. Затем добавляю в этот проект файл main.asm:

```
.386

.model flat, stdcall

ExitProcess proto:DWORD

.code

start:
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

Собираю проект и получаю ошибку:

*LINK : fatal error LNK1221: подсистема не может быть логически выведена, а должна быть определена*

В чем здесь дело и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Система должна знать, как загружать файл. Для этого линкер устанавливает специальные флаги в заголовке файла.

Нужно зайти в *Свойства конфигурации/Компоновщик/Система* и установить значение опции подсистема в требуемое, видимо, в *Консоль*. Или указать для линкера опцию */SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE*.